# Changing the properties of only one plot in a ybar

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Sorry I am sure there is a simple answer to this but I just can't find it! All I am trying to do is turn off the labels (I think they are called `nodes near coords`) on the second set of data, ie. the red ones.

Essentially, there must be a way of accessing the properties of only one data set on an axis?

As an aside, is there a way to provide some separation between each set of two columns, ie. have the separation between each set greater than the separation within the set.

Thanks in advance!

[image]

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ybar,
    height=7cm,
    width=\textwidth,
    legend style={at={(0.5,-0.2)},
      anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
    ylabel={Thousands of SHSs},
    xtick=data,
    nodes near coords,
    nodes near coords align={vertical},
    x tick label style={rotate=45,anchor=east},
    /pgf/number format/.cd,
        use comma,
        1000 sep={},
    xmin=1996.5,
    xmax=2013.5,
    tick pos=left,
    axis lines=left
    ]
\addplot table {
1997    0.2
1998    0.4
1999    1.2
2000    1.7
2001    3.2
2002    4.7
2003    12
2004    21
2005    28
2006    37
2007    70
2008    103
2009    170
2010    325
2011    470
2012    644
2013    901
};

\addplot table {
1997    0.2
1998    0.4
1999    1.2
2000    1.7
2001    3.2
2002    4.7
2003    7.8
2004    14
2005    19
2006    28
2007    48
2008    76
2009    114
2010    201
2011    237
2012    264
2013    292
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

%ref is http://c1cleantechnicacom.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/files/2011/12/SHSGrameenShakti-e1325237359995.gif
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add

```
nodes near coords=\empty
```

to the plot. The complete code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ybar,
    height=7cm,
    width=\textwidth,
    legend style={at={(0.5,-0.2)},
      anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
    ylabel={Thousands of SHSs},
    xtick=data,
    nodes near coords,
    nodes near coords align={vertical},
    x tick label style={rotate=45,anchor=east},
    /pgf/number format/.cd,
        use comma,
        1000 sep={},
    xmin=1996.5,
    xmax=2013.5,
    tick pos=left,
    axis lines=left
    ]
\addplot table {
1997    0.2
1998    0.4
1999    1.2
2000    1.7
2001    3.2
2002    4.7
2003    12
2004    21
2005    28
2006    37
2007    70
2008    103
2009    170
2010    325
2011    470
2012    644
2013    901
};

\addplot+[nodes near coords=\empty] table {
1997    0.2
1998    0.4
1999    1.2
2000    1.7
2001    3.2
2002    4.7
2003    7.8
2004    14
2005    19
2006    28
2007    48
2008    76
2009    114
2010    201
2011    237
2012    264
2013    292
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Or, as **Jake** mentions in [his comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/231539/changing-the-properties-of-only-one-plot-in-a-ybar#comment547637_231541), you can add `nodes near coords` just for the first plot:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ybar,
    height=7cm,
    width=\textwidth,
    legend style={at={(0.5,-0.2)},
      anchor=north,legend columns=-1},
    ylabel={Thousands of SHSs},
    xtick=data,
    nodes near coords align={vertical},
    x tick label style={rotate=45,anchor=east},
    /pgf/number format/.cd,
        use comma,
        1000 sep={},
    xmin=1996.5,
    xmax=2013.5,
    tick pos=left,
    axis lines=left
    ]
\addplot+[nodes near coords] table {
1997    0.2
1998    0.4
1999    1.2
2000    1.7
2001    3.2
2002    4.7
2003    12
2004    21
2005    28
2006    37
2007    70
2008    103
2009    170
2010    325
2011    470
2012    644
2013    901
};

\addplot table {
1997    0.2
1998    0.4
1999    1.2
2000    1.7
2001    3.2
2002    4.7
2003    7.8
2004    14
2005    19
2006    28
2007    48
2008    76
2009    114
2010    201
2011    237
2012    264
2013    292
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Or you could add the `nodes near coords` key only to the `\addplot [...]` options of the first plot.

Comment: @Jake Yes, I've added this to my answer. Thanks.

Comment: That's excellent, thanks very much Gonzalo :-)

Comment: Quick question - compiling the code complete per your minimum working example above puts the two bars nicely in front of one another so you can tell that they are "related". However, when I put this as part of my larger document, the bars sit side by side (see the screenshot above). Do you know whether any packages "interfere" with pgfplots to create this problem?

Comment: Just to answer my own question above: setting `ybar=-2pt` appears to correct this.